# Можно ли как-то приостановить показ баннеров AdMob?

Tags: java, android, admob

В приложении исправно показываются баннеры и все работает, но можно ли как-то временно отключить показ рекламы? Боюсь, что из-за малого количества скачиваний eCPM будет очень большим и аккаунт заблокируют.

Comment: возможно поможет установка минимальной запредельно высокой цены за 1000 показов

Comment: "**минимальной** запредельно высокой", не максимальной?

Comment: Не тянет на ответ - это комментарий

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Бояться такого можно, но вероятность мала.

У вас 2 пути.

1. Выпустить обнову приложения с отключённой рекламой и потом обновить опять с уже включённой. Это самый простой способ, но и самый кривой.
2. Встроить в код приложения обновляемый с сервера флаг, в зависимости от которого баннер будет скрываться/показываться. Сервер и обновление можно самому реализовать или заюзать FirebaseRemoteConfig - он прост и бесплатен.

Возможности сделать такое из настроек AdMob нет. Без внедрения условий показа скрытия баннера в коде - никак не сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте ввести ограничение показов в самом Admob:
[image: в настройках приложения]